# PHP Curl is not loading in PHP 7.3.3 for windows 8.1 64 bit

Tags: php, php-curl, adsapi-php.ini

I have gone through other similar questions but i cannot find a proper solution. I am a newbie to PHP. As per suggestions in youtube i have done php configuration with apache2.4 and php is working fine. I have enabled the extensions in php.ini file and uncommented curl dll. I refreshed the Apache and reloaded the web page but the Curl is not loaded. It seems in PHP 7 versions the configuration is dynamic in php.ini . I couldn't able to figure out where the changes needed to be done. Please help.

PHP 7.3.3 version php.ini file is attached here
[php.ini](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19HJZbCP4mbOqd_9HX-gP5pjg2e7vAxle)

Comment: @Shanteshwar Inde The link that you provided leads me to Php 5 version settings. But Php 7 seems to be different from php5. Please visit the link i added in the question so that you notice the differences

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde - a thread offering downloads of fixed PHP 5 libraries/extensions is not helpful.

Comment: Seems I have the same issue with PHP error `[20-Mar-2019 15:42:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.3/ext/php_curl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.3/ext/php_php_curl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 3):

This won't "fix" the bug, but you might try using the DLL from another version of PHP https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

I took `PHP 7.3.2 win32 VC15 x64`, and the `php_curl.dll` from it seems compatible with `PHP 7.3.3 Win32 VC 15`, which is my PHP installed version.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :)

Add the following to the end of Apache/conf/httpd.conf:

## load curl and open ssl libraries

LoadFile "C:/(path to php folder)/libssh2.dll"

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem, copy the following 3 files from the PHP root folder to the Apache's `bin` subfolder:

- `libeay32.dll`
- `libssh2.dll`
- `ssleay32.dll`

Then restart the Apache's service.

Comment: I only had libssh2.dll in my PHP7.4 root. Copying that worked (somehow)!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issues in this matter configuring in **httpd.conf** with the option

```
PHPIniDir=C:/PHP7
```

must test php, on extensions, on the command line with

```
php -m
```

Answer (score 0):

They have changed the paths. If you have installed PHP in C:\php7\ directory, then you need to put something like this in your php.ini file.

extension=/php7/ext/php_sockets.dll

Answer (score 0):

A Gotcha! on Windows, if you typically run one of several different versions of PHP, would be that your Apache referenced version might be out of sync with your windows environment var PHP version. Discovered this because I typically work with legacy code in various versions and oddly curl refused to load even though all the configuration in Apache and PHP were correct... Then I remembered my previous job was using PHP 5.4 As soon as I changed my env var to the current version of PHP Apache and PHP loaded curl